# How to use AppDelegate in other Classes

Tags: iphone, ios

How to use AppDelegate in other ViewController and What is the use of using AppDelegate in other ViewControllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access appDelegate Class like this:- and replace  AppDelegte with Your appDelegate class name

```
AppDelegte *appDelegate = (AppDelegte *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

and Call any ViewController By

```
[appDelegate.viewController nameOFViewController];
```

But must you Have make viewController Property ...

Answer (score 1):

The other answers all explain how to do it.

As for *why* you'd do it, you'd do it so that you can access properties that are stored in the app delegate, such as if you want to get access to the main window or main view controller.

In practice though, there are better ways to access both of those (self.view.window, and self.view.window.rootViewController respectively) and it's bad practice to store any other data in the app delegate - you should just use singletons/shared class instance if you want to store global data in your app (see how apple provides access to things like NSNotificationCenter, NSUserDefaults, etc).

So the short answer to "why would you" is *"You wouldn't. Next question?"*

Answer (score 0):

use this line

```
yourAppdelegate *appDelegate = (yourAppdelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```